# Working with a while loop in classes

Tags: python, class, while-loop

I'm new to working with classes, and I need to place a certain code inside a class. I've got the code working as intended outside of the class:

```
    minnum = 1
    maxnum = 100
    num = 1
    points = 0
    count = 9000
    while num in range(minnum, (maxnum + 1)):
        points += int(num + 300 * 2 * num / 3)
        num += 1
        if count < (points / 4):
            num -= 1
            break
    print num #Prints "19"
```

`count` should actually start at 0, but I put it to 9000 in the first example (whereas in the second I change `count` from 0 to 9000)

```
class numbers():
    def __init__(self):
        self.minnum = 1
        self.maxnum = 100
        self.num = 1
        self.points = 0
        self.count = 0
    def num(self):
        while self.num in range(self.minnum, (self.maxnum + 1)):
            self.points += int(self.num + 300 * 2 * self.num / 3)
            self.num += 1
            if self.count < (self.points / 4):
                self.num -= 1
                break
        return self.num
number = numbers()
number.count = 9000
print number.num #Prints "1"
```

What am I doing wrong? (I wanted `print number.num` to return the same value as in the first code, "19" not "1")

Comment: Have you actually called `number.num()`?

Comment: there are a couple of other differences in the two codes, so different behaviour isn't suprising at all. what the heck is `self.level`?

Comment: Using a `while` loop to iterate through a range of numbers is not very pythonic. Also making a new `range()` object *every* time you loop is not very efficient. Consider doing `for num in range(minnum, maxnum + 1):` instead.

Comment: @ChrisP yes i did, but that gave me an error. (turns out) i wasn't allowed to have the same name for the method and the variable.

Comment: @Joel Cornett thanks for the suggestion, originally my code used a for loop instead of a while loop, but i turned it to while for optimization, the maxnum could end up in thousands so if it was a for loop i'd get a delay whereas if it's a while loop i can make it pick up where it left off.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath it was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: @user3108546: If you are using python 2.7 or lower, use `xrange` instead of `range`. This will solve your efficiency problem. `range` returns a list of numbers, while `xrange` returns a generator which produces the numbers on demand. If you are using python 3, `range` acts identically to `xrange`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling the `num()` method in the second example, and you probably don't want to call a variable and a method by the same name ("num") either!

(As a matter of style, I'd also suggest that you initialise `count` via the `__init__` initialiser, rather than setting `count` directly)

```
def __init__(self, count):
    self.count = count
    # etc...

number = numbers(9000)
```

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question. Python doesn't allow me to call a variable the same thing as the method (so if i called the method i got an error if it had a variable by the same name)

The count variable is something that's constantly going to be changing (or growing) via a separate piece of code. For example every time a specific button is pressed count might grow by +50 which should affect the rest of the code.